# Testing Android App without destroying the Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-testing

I have tested my app for the scenario where the activity should destroy and restarts. Actually it automatically happens to destroy and restarts when any Ads are shown. Now I have to test my App flow for the scenario in which the app not destroyed and recreated. Any idea is highly appreciated

Comment: Don't add ads for testing.

Comment: I have to test with Ads

Comment: switch off your internet connection while running app btw why is the app destroyed when ads are shown?

Comment: If I switch off the internet then the Ads will not come. Actually I have to test it with Ads.    When showing Ads the app gets destroyed because the testing is done in a low profile device

Comment: Why don't you try it on an emulator?

Comment: That should be a good idea !. So other than changing the device we cant do anything right ?

Comment: @iappmaker showing some code would be helpful for you to get an answer and for us to give one if we have any

Answer (score 0):

I know why the app crashes when the Ads are displayed. The Google Play services are not updated.

To test your application, try running the app on a emulator with android 3.0+. With an emulator you can customize it to your wish.
You can change the RAM, internal storage capacity, resolution, skins etc. After opening the emulator, using DDMS, you can control all outside services like making a phone call to the emulator, giving it a fake location, sending SMS to the emulator etc.